# How can I approach this unit circle question with a spiral?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

> A point traces a unit circle if its coordinates satisfy $(x, y) = (\cos t,\sin t)$ as time t varies from $0$ to $2π$. Give an equation for a point that traces a spiral centred at $(0, 0)$ and that crosses the positive $x$-axis at $x = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ at times $t = 2π, 4π, 6π, \ldots$, and find its speed $v(t)$ at time $t$.

How can I approach this question ? I tried drawing the diagram out but it didn't make sense. Could someone help please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understood the text try to think the spiral as a "circle that wants to grow". It's starts in the origin, but the distance of the curve grows while "turning" like a circle. How can you do it analitically?

Comment: Try $(t \cos t, t \sin t)$.

Comment: $x = \cfrac{t}{2\pi} \cos t$ would work correct?

Comment: Yes... try it....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I tried splitting it into that, but I was still very confused

Comment: @MathLover How do you manage to get it to that form ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot of:  $\frac{t}{2 \pi}(\cos t, \sin t)$:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the graph! If this were in an exam or similar, how would I get the original expression with the aid of a graphing calculator to this form: t/2pi (cost,sint) please

Comment: Hey... think about it.  I think you can answer this on your own.

Comment: is it because it's in radians ?